# Abrir archivo PDF tipo BLOB desde Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebird

Tengo una base de datos en firebird la cual esta formada de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el campo RESUMEN tengo archivos PDF que corresponden a resumenes de afiliados de una obra social.
Quiero acceder desde mi aplicacion en Ruby on Rails y descargar ese archivo.
Estoy accediendo a la base de datos con este codigo pero al descargarlo me muestra un archivo pdf en blanco:

```
  def download
    month = params[:month]
    if current_user.role_provider?
      user = current_user.provider.id_persona
    else
      user = current_user.affiliate.id_persona
    end
    #traigo el mes seleccionado en la vista para hacer la query
    results1 = Aspurc::PersonaCCResumen.find_by(PERSONA_ID: user, MES: month)
    send_data(results1.resumen, filename: "Resumen_cuenta_corriente.pdf")
  end
```

Aclaro que el campo no me lo trae vacio, me trae toda una serie de caracteres que corresponden a ese pdf.

Adjunto imagen de el codigo de caracteres que visualizo cuando lo abro al pdf desde mi base de datos a menos que vaya hasta la pestaña 'AS PDF' que alli me muestra el PDF como deberia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde un editor de texto lo visualizo de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Eso te sucede al descargar cualquiera de los pdf o solo con uno/algunos? ¿has podido descargarlo al menos? ¿el pdf lo abres con tu explorador? ¿has probado a abrirlo con otro programa? ¿solo te muestra en blanco sin ningún mensaje de error? el archivo que descargas ¿trae información o solo es un archivo vacio con 0 bytes? si lo abres con un editor de texto cualquiera, ¿es efectivamente información como la que te encuentras en la bd para ese resumen?

Comment: Me sucede con cualquier archivo. Los he podido descargar bien y he intentado abrirlos con otro programa para PDF que no sea el navegador pero sucede los mismo. Me muestra todo en blanco sin ningun mensaje de error. Es un archivo que trae informacion ya que tiene un peso 'X', nunca es 0 Bytes. Si lo abro con un editor de texto me trae todo un conjunto de caracteres. Alli voy a adjuntar una foto para que se vea.

Comment: Pues parece traer la misma información. Ideas: [aquí](https://superuser.com/q/773343/100605) hay algunas respuestas de como validar la integridad de un pdf. En tu BD sale que el archivo pesa 85.476 bytes, ¿cierto? y el archivo descargado ¿pesa lo mismo? Veo que tu visor de bd tiene una pestaña "As Hex", aparte usas Sublime Text, podrías abrir el archivo descargado [en hexadecimal](https://facelessuser.github.io/HexViewer/) y comparar [la diferencia](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Compare%20Side-By-Side) a nivel de byte code entre lo que está en la bd y lo que descargaste.

Comment: Lo que he detectado es que 'results1.resumen' es un array por lo que cada posicion (results1.resumen[0], results1.resumen[1], etc) me trae un caracter por lo que a la hora de descargarlo me lo descarga bien con el peso que corresponde pero si lop abro esta en blanco